# Azure API gateway reroute urls based on tenant Id to backend application which are not hosted on Azure?

Tags: azure, routes, multi-tenant, azure-api-management, api-gateway

I have following requirement.

Currently we have different back-end public facing API applications(Not in Azure) for each tenant. We are building a mobile application. for that we have come up with an integration layer where we invoke multiple API's from our Back-end API applications using **Azure Logic Apps**.

This Logic APP url's further will be integrated with API Management.

But we are looking for the possibility to reroute the request to relevant back-end api application based on tenant id which we pass as query string parameter.

**Can any one please help me to understand whether Azure API gateway supports urls rerouting to external public facing applications (Backed applications are Not in Azure) ?**

We are planning to move back-end applications to AZURE but not near by. Mean while we wanted to have a solution.

Currently we are storing the Host name and Tenant ID in Table storage. So based on tenant id we are fetching the host name and forming the URL with relevant host name.

Any other alternative ideas are also highly appreciable.If you need any other information please let me know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the approach you are taking is the right one. The same in APIM can be achieved by using the [`set-backend-service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#SetBackendService) policy.

You could either fetch the hostname from table storage in APIM using the [`send-request`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies#SendRequest) policy ([cache the result](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-caching-policies) for better latency).

Or you can use [Named Values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-properties) to store the mappings and remove table storage altogether.

Comment: currently we are doing all these tenant based mapping's in a separate logic app and calling it as part of the base API which will do multiple back-end request's and aggregate the result and send it back.  But all these things we can do in APIM Policies level. So My question is will there be any advantage doing all these things in APIM Policies rather than doing it in a logic app/Durable functions? Is it just a flavor?

Comment: While it may be possible, APIM is best as a front for your APIs with features like security, rate limit, etc. and shouldn't really have lots of processing involved like aggregates. If the intention is just to route based a key like your original post, should be OK. But if you require processing of any kind, better to use Function/Logic Apps and just front them with APIM if required.